# Multiple command in java processbuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to create XML file of .smv file  by using multiple commands in process builder.how can i give command to the process builder in such a way that output of first command and next command generate next output

```
 Process p = null;

 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("nusmv","-int", "D:/files/bitshift.smv");

            p = pb.start();

            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream outS = null;

            StringBuffer commandResult = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            int readInt;

            int returnVal = p.waitFor();

            in = p.getInputStream();

            while ((readInt = in.read()) != -1)
                {commandResult.append((char)readInt);
            outS = (BufferedOutputStream) p.getOutputStream();
            outS.write("Process_model".getBytes());
            outS.write("show_traces -p 4 -o D:/output.xml".getBytes());}
            outS.close();

            System.out.println(commandResult.toString());
            in.close();
```

What should I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i give command to the process builder in such a way that output of first command and next command generate next output

If you mean how can you pipe commands together, have your `ProcessBuilder` start a command shell, and use the shell syntax for piping the commands together.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler to create a batch file and invoke the batch file from Java but if you must...

Example:  Chain two commands like

```
    c:\>dir | find "DIR"
```

which pipes the output of **dir** to **find**.

Here is an instructional example to do the above in Java.  This example simply writes the 
final output to a file but you can use a stream reader as in your existing code.  Tweak, 
add error checking, exception handing and optimize as necessary. ( and don't write
to root dir in a production application, use user temp).

```
    final ProcessBuilder processBuilder1 = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "dir", "c:\\");
    final ProcessBuilder processBuilder2 = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "find", "\"DIR\"");
    processBuilder1.redirectOutput(Redirect.to(new File("c:\\tmp1.tmp")));
    final Process process1 = processBuilder1.start();
    process1.waitFor();
    processBuilder2.redirectInput(Redirect.from(new File("c:\\tmp1.tmp")));
    processBuilder2.redirectOutput(Redirect.to(new File("c:\\tmp2.tmp")));
    final Process process2 = processBuilder2.start();
    process2.waitFor();
```

Restults:

tmp1.tmp

```
 04/02/2014  09:42 PM                 0 HaxLogs.log
 04/02/2013  12:42 AM                 0 lock
 04/02/2014  03:42 PM    <DIR>          mfg42
```

tmp2.tmp

```
 04/02/2014  03:42 PM    <DIR>          mfg42
```

Comment: Incomplete without telling us what the Redirect class is, or does, and this code won't always work with those waitFor() calls where they are now. They shouldn't be called until all the input has been read.

Comment: java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect

Comment: This example is writing to a file.  StdOut will not block.

Comment: it is just creating temp1.tmp but not creating temp2.tmp after second command

Comment: Could be due to 'find' filter not finding string 'DIR' or OS not finding 'find' command.

Comment: I stressed with a /s parameter and all works fine. 17m of data and 4m of find output (05/17/2014 11:05 AM 17,227,302 tmp1.tmp 05/17/2014 11:05 AM 4,424,560 tmp2.tmp ).